# How do I install Phoenix 2 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, miner-configuration, mining-software, installation, phoenix

I'm trying to install the latest version of [Phoenix2](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=75786) on Mac OSX Mountain Lion (on a Macbook Pro Retna) and unable to get it to work

What works:

- The [BitMinter](http://bitminter.com/) client says OpenCL works on my CPU and GPU (It's Java based)

What I've tried:

- The BitMinter client on older macs says OpenCL fails for the video card (which is expected)
- [This OpenCL Test Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12443976/328397) fails
- python -c "import numpy; print numpy.version.version"  returns 1.6.1
- Installing [PyOpenCL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopencl) by running `make` and `python configure.py`
- Running the command: `sudo easy_install --upgrade twisted`
- Checking dependencies: python setup.py --requires
- Installing Phoenix by running `sudo make install` and `sudo python ./setup.py install'
- Running Phoenix by typing `python phoenix.py example.py`

**Question**

Can anyone walk me through the process of installing Phoenix2 (or other client) on OSX?

I suspect I need to uninstall OpenCL, twisted, etc, and replace it with a download from http://www.macports.org/, among other tasks

Comment: Note that mining on an NVIDIA chipset is not likely ever to be profitable or even worthwhile. The NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M in that MBP-R won't likely see more than 100 Mhash/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following to install PyOpenCL.  It installed on my MBP 8,1 running ML:

```
git clone http://git.tiker.net/trees/pyopencl.git 
cd pyopencl
git submodule init
git submodule update
python configure.py
python setup.py build
make
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

GUIminer "just worked" on my late-2012 MBP-R.   https://github.com/downloads/pletoss/poclbm/guiminer-poclbm-macosx.dmg  ...Just drag it to a writeable folder somewhere.

Colin's comment is correct, of course-- the low-voltage/power-stingy GPU, though awesome for a laptop, is not a match for the desktop screamers serious miners use to heat their homes.  On the other hand, if you have an MBP you might as well put it to work.  (I'm clocking about 35Mh/s ...could maybe do better but I haven't yet been futzing with parameters.)